# Can I get the Rambam's correspondence with the French rabbis online?

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, internet, responsa, astrology

I recently read an article by Rabbi Yaacov Schwartz in the *Journal of Halacha and Contemporary Society* (Fall 1988) titled "Jewish Implications of Astrology." In the article, he quotes the Rambam in the letter he wrote to the rabbis of South France. Rabbi Schwartz also quotes one Alexander Marx, who discusses this responsa in [Vol. III of HUCA](http://www.jstor.org/stable/23502530?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (1926).

Can I find these letters online?

Comment: Followup question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61744/5323

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the research I did before asking this question was simply too good.

Marx reprints the letters at the end of his [article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/23502530?&seq=33#page_scan_tab_contents) (starting at page 343), which is available online for free through JSTOR.